# How can i get the selected item index number from the ListView control i created?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I created a ListView control class:

```
class ListViewNF : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListViewNF()
            {
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then in form1 top:

```
ListViewNF lvnf;
```

Then in the constructor:

```
        lvnf = new ListViewNF();
        lvnf.Location = new Point(250, 18);
        lvnf.Size = new Size(474, 168);
        lvnf.View = View.Details;
        this.SuspendLayout();
        lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
        lvnf.Columns.Add("From", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvnf.Columns.Add("Subject", 200);
        lvnf.Columns.Add("Date", 300);
        lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
        lvnf.ColumnClick += lvnf_ColumnClick;
        lvnf.Click += lvnf_Click;
        lvnf.SelectedIndexChanged += lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged;
        this.Controls.Add(lvnf);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Then in the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
void lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label9.Text = lvnf.inde
        }
```

But the SelectedIndex property not exist in the lvnf.
What i want to display in label9 is the current index of the item im at now in the ListView. If I clicked with the mouse on item 43 then show in label9 43.

Update what I tried and need

```
void lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(emailsIDSFile);
            label9.Text = lines[lvnf.SelectedIndices]
        }
```

I have a text file with strings inside of numbers for example:

"1"
"44"
"55"

And so on.
What I need to do is to get the line from the text file that is assosiate with the item index I selected.

For example if in the ListView I'm now clicking on the first item then from the text file i need to display in label9 the first line as number.
If I clicked the first item in the ListView and in the text file the first string is "55" then show 55 in label9

Then if I clicked on item number 76 in the ListView and the index is 76 then show the line number 76 from the text file for example line 76 is "8" then display in label9 the number 8.

Comment: `label9.Text = lvnf.SelectedItems[0].Index.ToString();`

Comment: You plan on reading a file every time the selection changes?  That's potentially a horrible performance hit.

Comment: You right then i will read the lines once each time i'm running the program into a List<string> and then use with the List in the event. Is that logic ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use use [`lvnf.SelectedItems` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx). If it allows to select only one item you can use `lvnf.SelectedItems[0].Index`

> When the MultiSelect property is set to true, this property returns a
>   collection containing the items that are selected in the ListView. For
>   a single-selection ListView, this property returns a collection
>   containing the only selected item in the ListView.

Comment: When i make selecteditems[0].index it's working when i click on one item but if i click again on any other item in the listview i'm getting exception:  InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'

Comment: Adding this check solved the exception: if (lvnf.SelectedItems.Count > 0)

Comment: @DanielLip: Of course. You should check if any is selected.